# Missing text in default body field

Tags: nodes

I am using the answers module. I suddenly observed that the body field text of the question and answer content type on my site is missing. When I go to the database, the information is intact.

The comment body  field is not affected.

Please what can be the cause?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you change something? theme ?

Comment: I found out it's because I uninstalled the Intenationalization module. Thanks.